# Plural na descrição das medalhas Aprimorador e Luminar

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, localização

50 e 500 tem que ser **`perguntaS`**:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E também:

- Ao estar dentro de Medalhas de Resposta, creio que ficaria melhor `Respondeu e editou...`.
- Acham que está claro que essa medalha se refere a responder e editar a *mesma* pergunta?

Comment: Acho que isso já foi reportado mas não encontro... Afinal era só um comentário: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2063/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-das-medalhas-explainer-refiner-e-illuminator/2064#comment6595_2064